# Makefile not working on Windows (mingw32-make, Error 255, unexpected at this time)

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw32

I have a makefile that works under Cygwin but when I try and run Mingw32-make.exe from cmd.exe I am encountering an error:

```
all: my_file

my_file: \
  static/XML/head.xml \
  ../lib/Dependencies/common/1.0 ../lib/Dependencies/licensing/1.0 ../lib/Dependencies/json/1.0 \
  src/common \
  src/MainFolder \
  static/XML/tail.xml
  $(build-file)

# Simple file and directory concatenation.
define build-file
@for dep in $^; do \
  if [ -d $$dep ]; then \
    for file in $$dep/*.lua; \
    do \
      cat $$file; \
      echo; \
    done \
  else \
    cat $$dep; \
    echo; \
  fi \
done > bin/$@.lua
@echo 'BUILT $@'
endef
```

When I try and run mingw32-make.exe I get the following error:

```
dep was unexpected at this time.
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'my_file' failed
mingw32-make: *** [my_file] Error 255
```

The file's indentation is set to tabs.

Nothing I've tried so far has worked. Can anyone please assist? What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Did you indent `$(build-file)` with a tab?

Comment: Yes, in the makefile all of my indentation is tabs.

Comment: On an unrelated issue. Listing directories as prerequisites of a target doesn't really work very well.

Comment: What shell is make using? `cmd.exe`? Yeah, quick test indicates that's a `cmd.exe` error string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code within the definition `define build-file... endef`
is to be executed by the shell in the host system.

It is `bash` script, `bash` being the usual shell in
linux (and cygwin). When you attempt to execute
the `make` natively in Windows with `mingw32-make.exe`,
the shell is the Windows shell, `cmd.exe`, which
does not understand `bash` script.

To work, your make will need to detect (or be told) whether
the host system is Windows or Linux(-like). Then you can
conditionally select a viable definition for `build-file`, e.g.

```
ifdef WINDOWS
define build-file
    ... cmd commands ...
endef
else
define build-file
    ... bash commands ...
endef
endif
```

**Afterthought**

Or, if you have a `bash.exe` from Cygwin in your Windows `PATH`,
you should just be able to put `SHELL = bash.exe` at the top of
your makefile to make `bash` the shell for your make.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm probably looking for.